# Compile error in java script library for Xpages

Tags: xpages, hcl-notes

Notes 10.0.1 FP3 causing below compile errors, but Notes 9.0.1 FP10 SHF81 doesn't have the same issue.  Is there a way to resolve this without having 9.0.1 installed?

1) Cannot nest 'IBM/Notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.105.3.20190810-1410'
2) Container 'IniVariable Java Library' references non-existing library 'IBM\Notes\Data\SwPDFC\java\ver6.20.000\swpdfc-2.0.0.jar'

[image]

Comment: Without looking at the JS written it is anybody’s guess what is happening. So provide a sample that fails. The giveaway is the version number: R9 used Java6. Now it’s Java8 and OpenJDK. Referenced a hard coded library perhaps?

Comment: 9.0.1 FP10 uses Java 8 too.

Comment: Can you post the content of the “Ini Variable Java Library”? I don’t think that’s a standard piece

Comment: The 'IniVariable' error disappeared after a clean install.  The first error is still present, but I have figured out the issue per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your using the SWING PDF Converter. Maybe you should try to reinstall the Converter or maybe you have to look if there's a newer version that is compatible with Notes version 10. As `stwissel` pointed out Notes version 10 uses Java8 and OpenJDK, so maybe a newer version of the SWING PDF Converter is the solution.

Comment: I would agree that could be the issue with the second error about 'IniVariable' and that actually disappeared after a clean install.  However, the first error about 'Cannot nest' was still a problem that I have figured out per my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new blank database it automatically includes 'Plug-in Dependencies' which appear to pull in everything in the 'Notes\framework\rcp\eclipse\plugins' folder which includes the referenced plug-in shown in the error message.  The problem is when you add a new variable classpath entry and select ECLIPSE_HOME, then navigate to the same 'Notes\framework\rcp\eclipse\plugins' location.

If you select a different folder for your new variable classpath entry or remove either the 'ECLIPSE_HOME' or 'Plug-in Dependencies' from your Build Path Libraries the error goes away.  I have included the below screenshot showing what I mean.

[image: Cannot nest compile error]

Since the Extension Library was rolled into the Notes core it must now be part of the Plug-in Dependencies causing a conflict when being added via the IniVariable option for those using 10.0.1.  I still need to confirm the build path with a co-worker who has Notes 9.0.1 FP10 SHF81.